# Eloquent multiple where from date fields <= >=

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to select Items from mySql table.
I use Laravel 5.2 & Eloquent

My table structure:
id | item_id | name | date_start | date_end

- id = primary, auto
- item_id = int
- name = text
- date_start & date_end is 'Date' Type and have following format '2016-09-14'

*my query:*

```
$dateFormated = date('Y-m-d',$tempDate);
$items = ItemList::where('item_id', $id)
  ->where('date_start', '>=', $dateFormated)
  ->where('date_end', '<=', $dateFormated)
  ->get()
```

If I **remove one** of my where **clauses I get correct results** for all Items with the right date_start/date_end value.

**what am I doing wrong, what can I do?**

Comment: try `between` condition.

Comment: @urfusion : According to me, `between` does not give more perfection than `>=, <=`.

Comment: @Virb according to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), between does exactly the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to swap the operators and you'll be good to go

```
  ->where('date_start', '<=', $dateFormated)
                         ^
  ->where('date_end',   '>=', $dateFormated)
                         ^
```

According to the data provided in comments, `date_start` must fall on or **before** the `formattedDate` and `date_end` after, hence your conditions were opposite of what they should have been.

---

Old Answer

```
  ->where('date_start', '>=', $dateFormated)
  ->where('date_end', '<=', $dateFormated)
```

How can a start date and end date be compared to the same date unless you want to look for records for only 1 specific date?

Syntax is fine but logic might not be. Such a query will result in something like this

```
WHERE date_start>="2016-09-13" and date_end<="2016-09-13"
```

Are you sure you're looking for those records?

That is exactly why you get good results when you remove one where clause related to the dates - those events are not starting and ending on the same date.

As confirmed in comments, this actually ***is*** the problem. `WHERE` clause is not logical according to the requirements. Solution is in using **[orWhere](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_orwhere)**

Comment: yep I sure... the search date must be inside the range of start/end date.
if start_date is 2016-01-01 and end_date 2016-01-31 the $dateFormated is 2016-01-12.

Comment: given your example you end up with the following expression  "2016-01-01">="2016-01-12" and "2016-01-13" <="2016-09-12" This is false. You need to revers the greater and smaller than signs.

Answer (score 0):

It's help me

```
    if($start_date!=''){
            $q->whereDate('date_start', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)));
    }
    if($end_date!=''){
            $q->whereDate('date_end', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)));
    }
```

try it, hope can help.

Comment: sorry, no. result is the same... empty array :(